# What happened to the appearance of Physics Stack Exchange all on a sudden?

Tags: discussion

Physics Stack Exchange is changed!

Even at 11:30-12:00 IST, the site was as usual. But when I visited the site again at 2 IST, the appearance of Physics SE. was different!

Picture speaks more than words:

- This is the snapshot of a question of mine at the *past*:
  [image]

Now, it appears as:
[image]

- This is my profile icon with small badges:

[image]

But now it looks like this with bigger badges:

[image]

- Then:

[image]

Now with the favourite mark star appearing smaller:

[image]

- Then;

[image]

Now:

[image]

- Now:

[image]

Then:

[image]

- Then:

[image]

Now:

[image]

And many others like the favourite, reviews, responses numbers are marked in blue while then they were marked in red; and the most important the logo of *Physics Meta Stack Exchange* contains only *me*.

That'all what grabbed my notice.

So, what actually happened? Is my laptop not working or something else has happened?

Comment: Yes, this has been reported by several users in chat, so it's not your laptop. This could be the coming online of the site design update, or just some form of hiccup - hopefully someone from the team can clarify?

Comment: Also of note is the clipped `Physics me` banner on meta.

Comment: These layout issues seem related to the change of the sidebar width, cf. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272563/209806

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty: _Then_ was really better.

Comment: @Qmechanic Those are meant to start rolling out tomorrow, right? In any case, they're mostly not layout changes - there are image, font and colour changes. But yeah, mostly CSS tweaks.

Comment: While I see a difference, I don't know that I'd say one is 'better' than another. They do the exact same thing: give you information.

Comment: Downvote?? Why??? Shouldn't I've the right to know why those things changed?? Really ridiculous!!

Comment: I downvoted because I don't think it's worth a meta post to complain about the design. Nor is it necessary to overload with images (think of the mobile users!) as you've done here (and, IIRC, in the past as well). And after toying with it some, I actually like the new design

Comment: @Kyle Kanos: How could you deduce that I'm complaining? I wanted to know what was actually going on? Was it some bug or some laptop problem or something else.... Query and not any Complain:/

Comment: The tone, for one. "*Then* was better" - [you, about 15 hours ago](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7399/what-happened-to-the-appearance-of-physics-stack-exchange-all-on-a-sudden?noredirect=1#comment29167_7399), for 2.

Comment: @Kyle Kanos: And of course, you can like the new design; no one hindered you to do that. It's your personal opinion.

Comment: @Kyle Kanos: I'm still saying _then_ was better; but have I used any kinds of words or sentence that intends to this view in my question? I had posted this as a comment. Now, if you can't understand what I am asking and meddle the query with a comment, then sorry....

Comment: Call it what you want, but this whole thing reads as you lodging a complaint about the design.

Comment: @Kyle Kanos: Again that's your own view. It's your personal matter.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure you're getting worked up over a downvote on Meta. There is no rep loss associated with it, just someone disagreed with either your premise or thought that the question wasn't worth the post (or other reasons I'm not thinking of).

Comment: @Kyle Kanos: Question was never of any reputation loss or downvote; I've got many downvotes earlier but if this type of question which asks for some info gets downvoted, then really it is annoying. You can downvote. But the reason you cited.... beggar's description.

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty: Hurrah! Profiles have changed!!